# Google Map API url

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps in my project. I recently read that from Jun 11th 2018 it will be mandatory to include Google Map API key while calling maps APIs to load a Google Map. I have few queries regarding this. The answers to these questions will help me to plan this transition for my various project releases:

1) Currently to load Google Maps into my project, I'm calling the map APIs using a URL:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

For my current project, maps load perfectly fine. Although it gives me warning to include Google Map API key and remove sensor parameter (as it is no longer suupported). So, my question is if I continue to use the same EXACT url what will be the Google Maps behaviour after Jun 11th 2018. Some says Google Maps will continue to load but with a watermark -- saying for development purposes only. Please confirm this behaviour, is it VALID for above url as well or this url is NOT supported at all.

2) For my new releases, what should be my new URL to call Google Maps APIs. It suppose it should be:

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please confirm.

Comment: Adding a snippet from 3rd para from the article (https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/) ---- "This will go into effect on June 11th, and keyless access will no longer be supported. At that time, keyless calls to the Maps JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps watermarked with “for development purposes only.”" --- This clearly says low resolution maps shall be supported for Maps JavaScript API without map key. I just want to confirm whether my url will continue to be supported with low resolution or not?

Comment: So what exactly isn't clear from what you already read? *keyless calls to the Maps JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps watermarked with “for development purposes only.”* I don't think it can be any clearer than that...

Comment: Yes that's true it clearly states that but my question is specific to the Google Map API url that I'm using currently, i.e., <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>  Please note this url works perfectly fine for me right now and is different from the latest API url without a key (refer to second url in my question).

Comment: Do you have a Premium API access (Google Maps APIs for Work Customers)? Because as far as I know, these URLs are for Premium access. If you do, then you should get support directly from Google as this should be included in your plan. If not, I would suppose it's safe to switch to the "standard" URL.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?__utma=102347093.1260464105.1522094885.1525744636.1525744636.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1525744636&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1525744636.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=160549437&_ga=2.252690697.1400932236.1525737695-1260464105.1522094885) confirms that if you don't sign up for an api key it will not work.

To sign up for an api key go [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/#get-started).

The article says, "Also, in June 2016 we announced that we would stop supporting keyless usage, meaning any request that doesn’t include an API key or Client ID."

Hopefully this was helpful.

**Update**

It will not return anything at all. In other words, keyless calls will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Adding a snippet from 3rd para from the article (https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/) ---- "This will go into effect on June 11th, and keyless access will no longer be supported. At that time, keyless calls to the Maps JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps watermarked with “for development purposes only.”" --- This clearly says low resolution maps shall be supported for Maps JavaScript API without map key. I just want to confirm whether my url will continue to be supported with low resolution or not?

Comment: It will show basic map with watermarks, but you wan't use any client side service like geocoding, directions or places library.